# How do I make PR link after commit message?

Tags: github, pull-request

[image]

This is a screenshot of gitmoji's folder structure. How do I make link to PR just like blue color of #number in this picture?
I want to make this kind of link without using squash and merge!! I want to use original merge commit.

Comment: [FYI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FYI): Pull requests are not part of the base Git software: they're add-ons, provided by GitHub (GitHub PRs) and Bitbucket (Bitbucket PRs). GitLab has "merge requests", MRs, instead of PRs. All three have various minor (but important) differences in how they handle them.

Answer (score 0):

If a commit message, issue, discussion or pull request comment has a `#` followed by a numver that's a valid pull request/issue/discussion id, it will automatically format it.

If you add `#5` to your commit message and pull request #5 exists, GitHub will create a blue link to it.

Comment: But before create PR, We can't know PR number! How do I set #number next to commit message?

Comment: Normally, the PR message would be added in the merge commit. Aside from that, you can create draft PRs and add the relevant commit after creating the commits. If you look at gitmoji, you can see that the PR references are [not part of any commit inside the PR](https://github.com/carloscuesta/gitmoji/pull/1013/commits) but only in the merge commits.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add PR number after your commit message

```
 You can search last PR number using git API:
    https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=sha:<sha-code>
```

> it will give json output; PR is for example "number": 10,

Just do git log and paste sha code there of last commit
and you will get the PR number of last commit.
**Your Current PR number: add +1 to it.**

Comment: Note that somebody else might create another PR between the API request and the actual creation of the PR.